Ubuntu 24.04 Wifi Adapter not found
I should start I am new to the linux world.
I have followed the Ubuntu guide, but I am not having luck getting Ubuntu to recognize my wifi adapter. As a note, I am using USB tethering for an internet connection at the moment.
here is a log file detailing my network details.
the network adapter appears to be a
MEDIATEK Corp. Device

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 03 Dec 2024 08:45 EST -0500

Booted last: 03 Dec 2024 00:00 EST -0500

Script from: 27 Aug 2024 10:55 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.8.0-49-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov  4 02:06:24 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]
  Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:5524]

03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mendocino [1002:1506] (rev c1)
  Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Mendocino [1025:1654]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3594 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0461:4141 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP 320M USB Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f2:b79c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd ACER HD User Facing
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
  Soft blocked: no
  Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

acer_wmi               36864  0
sparse_keymap          12288  1 acer_wmi
platform_profile       12288  1 acer_wmi
wmi_bmof               12288  0
video                  73728  2 acer_wmi,amdgpu
wmi                    28672  3 video,acer_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### dkms #############################

./wireless-info: line 206: dkms: command not found

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
  inet 192.168.31.51/24 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
     valid_lft 3252sec preferred_lft 3252sec
  inet6 fe80::6c37:7299:27f4:4cf5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
     valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.31.14 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto dhcp src 192.168.31.51 metric 100 
192.168.31.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.31.51 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

  NetworkManager

Running:

root         911       1  0 08:38 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.8.0-49-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:03:00.3-usb-0:1:1.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       59746960-2f86-35cf-bdc0-4530f180bc16
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.31.51/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.31.14
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.31.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.31.14, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.31.14
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.31.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_client_identifier = 01:<MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.31.14
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.31.14
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1733236763
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = sam-Aspire-A315-24PT
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        ip_address = 192.168.31.51
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.31.14
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = 192.168.31.14
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::6c37:7299:27f4:4cf5/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   59746960-2f86-35cf-bdc0-4530f180bc16 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/lib/netplan/00-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    4.969139] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x06001000
[    4.970062] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.30 DEC: 3 VEP: 0 Revision: 4
[   40.415053] rndis_host 1-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: renamed from usb0

########## wireless info END ############



That wifi isn't supported and I am not sure why

where did you see that? how can you tell?

Do a search on the net for "linux ID 14c3:7902"
